# Split Business days in respective month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1

```
no  From        To          check   
1   27-Jan-20   28-Mar-20   a                                    
2   28-Mar-20   12-Apr-20   a                                 
3   29-May-20   29-May-20   b                             
4   5-Apr-20    12-Apr-20   b
```

df2

```
col1    col2
a       9-Apr-20
b       30-Mar-20
```

df

```
no  From        To          check   total   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1   27-Jan-20   28-Mar-20   a       45      5   20  20                                  
2   28-Mar-20   12-Apr-20   a       9           2   7                               
3   29-May-20   29-May-20   b       1                   1                           
4   5-Apr-20    12-Apr-20   b       5               5
```

i need to calculate 2 things

1. column "Total" based on working days between "From" and "To" and include any holiday from df2.
2. split the "Total" column in respective months (Jan to Dec columns)

For part 1 :
The column "total" in df1 is calculated using

```
np.busday_count('2020-01-27','2020-03-28')
```

but this is not acurate and not able to include holiday(df2)in this
i tried to directly create dataframe using

```
df['total']=np.busday_count(df1['From'].astype('datetime64[D]')
,df1['To'].astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

but it is giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`bdate_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html) in a custom function

```
# dict of num to month mapping
months = pd.tseries.frequencies.MONTH_ALIASES

df2['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['col2'], dayfirst=True)

# holiday month
df['holiday'] = df['check'].map(df2.set_index(['col1'])['col2']).dt.month

def count_by_month(s):

      start, end, holiday = s['From'], s['To'], s['holiday']

      valid_dates = pd.bdate_range(start=start, end=end).month
      count = dict(pd.Series(valid_dates).value_counts())

      # subtract holidays
      if holiday in count:
         count[holiday] -= 1
    
      return pd.concat([s, pd.Series({v: count.get(k, 0) for k, v in months.items()})], axis=0)

print(df)

   no         From            To check  total  holiday  JAN  FEB  MAR  APR  \
0   1    27-Jan-20     28-Mar-20     a     45        4    5   20   20    0   
1   2    28-Mar-20     12-Apr-20     a      9        4    0    0    2    7   
2   3    29-May-20     29-May-20     b      1        3    0    0    0    0   
3   4    5-Apr-20      12-Apr-20     b      5        3    0    0    0    5   

   MAY  JUN  JUL  AUG  SEP  OCT  NOV  DEC  
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  
1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  
2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  
3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: thanks a lot its working. but for row 2 , for april it should be 7 as per holiday in df2. need to include holiday as per a or b

Comment: also, how did you calculated the total column?

Comment: @aimt for row 2, it should be 10 actually not 9. `total` is the sum of all month for each row

Comment: yes it should be 10, but if we include df2, for row 1 "check" is a and in df2  a= 9 april. so if we include this it will be 9. we need to remove holidays,based on "check" and df2 list

Comment: @aimt check the edit, hope it helps, please accept the answer